# Magento 1.9.2 Internal server error

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I got Internal server error in frontend only.

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@test.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

But my admin page is loaded. I got error only in frontend.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Look in the server's error logs to see what the problem is.

Comment: Check your var/log/ files

Answer (score 0):

Take a backup and delete everything inside var folder.

Answer (score 0):

When I get these kind of errors, they are most likely caused by an error in my .htaccess syntax.